# Global cartogram in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, cartogram

I am trying to create a global cartogram using the cartogram package in R. I am trying to use the data from wrld_simpl. What I expect is a cartogram in which the Population ("Pop2005" variable) is plotted. The code I have developed is this:

```
data(wrld_simpl)
world<-wrld_simpl

world_sf = st_as_sf(world)
world_sf_proj = st_transform(world_sf, crs = 3785)

world_cartogram <- cartogram_cont(world_sf_proj, "POP2005")
plot(world_cartogram)
```

Nonetheless, this has resulted in the following figure:
[image]

Do you know what is wrong with the code? Maybe the CRS? I have tried to use others CRS but I got the following error:
"Error: Using an unprojected map. This function does not give correct centroids and distances for longitude/latitude data:
Use "st_transform()" to transform coordinates to another projection."

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html), it is stated that

> The default plot of an sf object is a multi-plot of all attributes, up
> to a reasonable maximum

If you want to use the base R `plot` function, then use `st_geometry(your_map)` to plot (the geometry) an `sf` object.

Another possibility (which I don't recommend) is to set plot options to 1 plot maximum (`options(sf_max.plot=1)`), but this plots the first variable, and it might not be the best idea.

```r
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(cartogram)
library(tidyverse)

world_sf = st_as_sf(world)
world_sf_proj = st_transform(world_sf, crs = 3785)
world_cartogram <- cartogram_cont(world_sf_proj, "pop")

plot(st_geometry(world_cartogram))
```

[image]

---

Now, `sf` is particularly well suited with `ggplot2` and the tidyverse. In that setting, just use `ggplot` in combination with `geom_sf`.

```r
ggplot(world_cartogram) +
  geom_sf()
```